# Creating a google map

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, coordinates

I am going to go out on a limb here and ask if someone knows any good solution on how to map coordinates on a world map without using Google maps. I tried searching Google but didn't find anything relevant (I might have been searching a bit poorly :P).
It doesn't have to be a very exact map, but I would like to be able to have an image of a map and actually be able to point out where New York is.

I guess I would try to get a map first, and then try to use it as a canvas for a JavaScript that paints the different geo coordinates. The problem is that I am not sure on how to adjust the map to the correct coordinates.

Does anyone know anything about this or any way on how to get around this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged as ruby?

Comment: Writing the project in Ruby On Rails. Not sure if it was relevant but am currently using a gem called geocoder. Would like to minimize the usage of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you can't use Google Maps API, but there is also [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reason is that I don't wanna limit the number of request I do to google maps API. I just plan on having a simple map on my frontpage and if I am scaling my project I might have to start paying to google :P